# How can I specify another folder for a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I moved my Docker container files to another folder. Now when I want to start (or delete) the container, Docker Desktop throws an error:

> Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: exit status 1

I know it's because of the moved files, because if I go to the container details, Docker Desktop displays the old path on the top:

[image: old path]

How can I change the path to the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start and stop your containers using `docker-compose up` instead of Docker Desktop, it tends to be less buggy.

If you want to use Docker Desktop no matter what, delete the old containers using `docker rm` and running `docker-compose up` in the new directory.